# Display content on all days besides on Wednesday between specific times

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to display a div every day besides Wednesday between 3pm CST & Midnight or 11:59pm on that same Wednesday. Below is the code I have so far that is not working? This is my first time with the if date function so it's all new to me.

```
<?php 
if (date('w') == '1' | == '2' | == '4' | == '5' | == '6' | == '0') {
    //info to show Mon, Tue, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun all day. 
  }
else if (date('w') == 3){
 if (date('H') >= 15 && date('H') < 0) {
    //Content to show on Wednesday from 3pm to midnight 
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: note: or's are supposed to be `||`

Comment: and the rest of the syntax is invalid anyway. in_array() would be easier

Comment: Your conditional statement needs to be checked for logic error

    `if (date('w') == '1' || date('w') == '2' || date('w') == '4' || date('w') == '5' || date('w') == '6' || date('w') == '0') ...`

Comment: As I see the answers stream in, this has question become "how to write the most concise if...else statement"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` is the bitwise operator. `||` is the logical OR operator.

[PHP operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php).

Also, here's a more efficient version of what you wanted:

```
if (date('w') == 3) {
    if (date('H') >= 15) {
        //Content to show on Wednesday from 3pm to midnight 
    }
} else {
    //info to show Mon, Tue, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun all day. 
}
```

Comment: +1 for the else statement - smacking my head about why I didn't think of that :) the hour will never be less than zero though.

Comment: so your excluding the potential of time travel ?

Comment: Fair enough - if I travelled back in time I'd be making sure I was still checking this website for updates, so best factor that in!

Answer (score 2):

Your if comparison needs the date variable in each case, a better idea might be to use a temporary array to check:

```
if(in_array(date('w'), array(0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6))) {
    // info to show except Wed
} else {
    // w is 3
    if(date('H') >= 15) {
        // Content to show on Wed from 3pm to midnight
    }
}
```

*Note:*

- The else is implicit that the day number will be 3, since you've specified all other possibilities in the first clause.
- The hour will never be less than zero, but if it's between 3pm and midnight it will always be greater than 15, so removed the second part

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for comparing with different values is all wrong. You have to repeat the comparison, and combine them with the boolean `or` operator `||`

```
$w = date('w');

if ($w == 1 || $w == 2 || $w == 4 || $w == 5 || $w == 6 || $w == 0) {
    //info to show Mon, Tue, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun all day. 
} else if ($w == 3 && date('H') >= 15) {
    //Content to show on Wednesday from 3pm to midnight
}
```

Of course, you could also simplify the first condition to `if ($w != 3)`.

Your test `date('H') < 0` can never be true -- there are no negative hours on the clock. I guess you meant `< 24`, but that's unnecessary, since all hours are less than 24.

Answer (score 0):

Three things I can see that are not correct:

1. `| ==` should be `|| ==` , but I've simplified into a single `if` statement as it appears you're only interested in knowing if it's after 3pm on a Wednesday.
2. Logically, you cannot be `>= 15 && <0` - so this will never be true.
3. The `date()` function returns a string and you are comparing with an integer `== 3` (PHP will probably juggle types just fine but I've thrown in an intval() for a belt-and-braces approach).

Try this:

```
<?php 
    if (intval(date('w')) == 3 && intval(date('H')) >= 15) {
        // it's after 3pm on a Wed...
    }
?>
```